# Creating a list from json returns [object Object] and only last li

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm learning how to use a JSON response. I want it to display all 6 items from my [json](https://api.myjson.com/bins/e4ei2). Why do I get only the last item and `[object Object]` before it?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/e4ei2',
      async: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(result) {
        var item = "";
        $.each(result, function(index, val) {

          for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
            var item = val[i];
            console.log(item.stand);
            console.log(item.dishName);
            console.log(item.dishPrice);
            item += " <li><div class='content'><div class='stand-wrapper'><h2 class='stand'>" + item.stand + "</h2></div><div class='dish-wrapper'><p class='dish'>" + item.dishName + "</p></div><div class='price-wrapper'><p class='price'>" + item.dishPrice + "</p></div></div></li>";
          }
          $('ul').html(item);
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ofy6tbeu/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, remove the `async: false` setting. It's *very* bad practice, and you don't need it anyway as you're using callbacks correctly.

Then you need to loop through `result.menu`, not `result`. You're also redeclaring `item` within each iteration of the loop. You set it equal to `val[i]` which is an object. As you then attempt to concatenate this to a string it gets coerced to `[object Object]`, which you then see in the output.

A better approach would be to have a single loop through `menu`. Then you can access it's properties directly when creating the HTML string. You can achieve this by using `map()`:

```js
var result = {
  "menu": [{
    "stand": "Boucherie",
    "dishName": "Faux-filet",
    "dishPrice": "3,45 €"
  }, {
    "stand": "Pâtisserie",
    "dishName": "Mille feuilles",
    "dishPrice": "1,10 €"
  }, {
    "stand": "Le poissonier",
    "dishName": "Filet de bar au citron",
    "dishPrice": "4,60 €"
  }, {
    "stand": "Salad bar",
    "dishName": "Divers crudités"
  }, {
    "stand": "Les Côcottes",
    "dishName": "Rougail saucisse",
    "dishPrice": "2,80 €"
  }, {
    "stand": "Snack",
    "dishName": "Hot-dog",
    "dishPrice": "1,89 €"
  }]
};

// in your AJAX handler:
var html = result.menu.map(function(val) {
  return '<li><div class="content"><div class="stand-wrapper"><h2 class="stand">' + val.stand + '</h2></div><div class="dish-wrapper"><p class="dish">' + val.dishName + '</p></div><div class="price-wrapper"><p class="price">' + val.dishPrice + '</p></div></div></li>';
});
$('ul').html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for this very complete answer. I will look into it.

Comment: No problem. Here's an updated fiddle link showing it working: https://jsfiddle.net/ofy6tbeu/8/

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({ 
  type : 'GET', 
  url : 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/e4ei2', 
  async : false, 
  dataType : 'json', 
  success : function(result){
   var item="";
    $.each(result, function(index, val){ 

      for(var i=0; i < val.length; i++){ 
        var data = val[i]; 
      /*  console.log(data.stand);
        console.log(data.dishName);
        console.log(data.dishPrice); */
        item+=" <li><div class='content'><div class='stand-wrapper'><h2 class='stand'>"+data.stand+"</h2></div><div class='dish-wrapper'><p class='dish'>"+data.dishName+"</p></div><div class='price-wrapper'><p class='price'>"+data.dishPrice+"</p></div></div></li>"; 
      } 
      $('ul').html(item);
    });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="logo-wrapper">
        </div>
        <ul>
           
        </ul>
      
    </div>
```

Please check this. You are using the global variable inside your for loop. I hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes from his fiddle.

Comment: Indeed I edited my fiddle to remove unnecessary code